# All Accumulation points of a set

Tags: limits, analysis

Let $M = \{\frac{k}{2^m} \mid k,m \in \mathbb N, k\le m \} $.

I showed that zero is an accumulation point of this set by looking at the sequence $(x_n)=\frac{n}{2^n} \in M$(without zero) which obviously converges towards zero.
But how can I show that this is the only accumulation point?

Can someone help? :)

Comment: But that would mean that every number in [0,1] is an accumulation point of M?!

Comment: But the given set says $k \le m$. Did you see that?

Comment: No In didn't.... I read it wrong.Thanks @Blue2001. So my above comment isn't true.

Answer (score 1):

We have $M\subseteq \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$, so $\overline{M}\subseteq \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$.

> Let $0<a\leq \frac{1}{2}$ arbitrary, fixed. We find $m_a\in\mathbb{N}$, so that
> \begin{align*}
> 0<\frac{m_a}{2^{m_{a}}}<a\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
> We see in (1) that $\frac{m_a}{2^{m_{a}}}\in M$ and only a finite number of elements in $M$ is between $\frac{m_a}{2^{m_{a}}}$ and $a$, namely $$\left|\left\{\left.\frac{k}{2^m}\right|1\leq m<m_a,1\leq k\leq m\right\}\right|=\sum_{m=1}^{m_a-1}m=\frac{1}{2}\left(m_a-1\right)m_a.$$ Thus we can find an $\varepsilon>0$ small enough so that $(a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)\cap M=\emptyset$ and $a$ is not a limit point.